# Can we get same url is open in multiple tabs in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update sessionId for my website if website is open in multiple tabs in same browser? meaning is each tab contains unique sessionID for the same url in React JS.

I tried to update sessionID if url is manually opened but if we click on duplicate then sessionID will also be duplciate with all the data of the site. so here I only need help for duplicate scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution here I'm going to post the code

```
    var navigationEntries = window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
    if (navigationEntries.length > 0) {
      var navigationType = navigationEntries[0] as PerformanceNavigationTiming;

      if (navigationType.type === "back_forward") {
        let sessionID = sessionStorage.getItem("session_id");
        sessionID = generateGuid();
        sessionStorage.setItem("session_id", sessionID);
      }
    }
```

here the solution works for below scenarios:

1. reload the tab sessionId will be same as old one
2. if you duplicate tab then sessionId will be updated
3. If manually open same tab then also sessionId will be updated

but this code won't work for below scenarios:

1. if user clicks back/forward arrows of browser in your website then sessionId will be updated